# Use Google Apps Script to Query the HubSpot API using Access token instead of API key

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-sheets, hubspot

I am trying to get hubspot records into a google sheets file. Honestly I am totally not skilled in coding. I found a tutorial for using google script, the point is that now the hubspot API key has been deprecated so the script doesn't work

so what should I change in the below code? I assume I should provide the access token but I don't now how to code it...

`

```
function callHsapi() {

var API_KEY = "YOUR_HUBSPOT_API_KEY"; // Replace YOUR_HUBSPOT_API_KEY with your API Key

var url = "https://api.hubapi.com/crm/v3/objects/contacts?limit=10&archived=false&hapikey=YOUR_HUBSPOT_API_KEY"; // Replace YOUR_HUBSPOT_API_KEY with your API Key

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);

var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

var results = data['results'];

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

var header = ["Company", "Create Date", "Email", "First Name", "Last Modified Date", "Last Name", "Phone", "Website"];

var items = [header];

results.forEach(function (result) {

items.push([result['properties'].company, result['properties'].createdate, result['properties'].email, result['properties'].firstname, result['properties'].lastmodifieddate, result['properties'].lastname, result['properties'].phone, result['properties'].website]);

});

sheet.getRange(1,1,items.length,items[0].length).setValues(items);

results.forEach(function (result) {

Logger.log(result['properties']);

});

}
‍
```

So I tried to edit the url (removing the api key) and then I pasted a few rows of code I found online the var option

```
function callHsapi() {

var url = "https://api.hubapi.com/crm/v3/objects/contacts?limit=10&archived=false"; // Replace YOUR_HUBSPOT_API_KEY with your API Key

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);

var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

var results = data['results'];

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

var header = ["Company", "Create Date", "Email", "First Name", "Last Modified Date", "Last Name", "Phone", "Website"];

var items = [header];

results.forEach(function (result) {

items.push([result['properties'].company, result['properties'].createdate, result['properties'].email, result['properties'].firstname, result['properties'].lastmodifieddate, result['properties'].lastname, result['properties'].phone, result['properties'].website]);

});

var option = {

  "headers": { "authorization": "Bearer " + "###YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN###" },
  "contentType": "application/json"
};

sheet.getRange(1,1,items.length,items[0].length).setValues(items);

results.forEach(function (result) {

Logger.log(result['properties']);

});

}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current issue. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue? And, can you provide the official document of the API you want to use?

Comment: FWIW. HubSpot has two [authentication methods](https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/api/intro-to-auth): [OAuth](https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/api/working-with-oauth), and [private app](https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/api/private-apps) access tokens. Previously there was a third method _HubSpot API Keys_ but these were deprecated on November 30, 2022 and are no longer supported. The HubSpot API Docs include [Migrate an API key integration to a private app](https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/api/migrate-an-api-key-integration-to-a-private-app).